# How to set a dateTime style in SSMS to generate scripts for table dateTime data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need copy a table data from one server to another server. I do it by SSMS ->task->generate scripts, select table select "data only", it created script like

```
INSERT [dbo].[Order] ([LastModifiedBy], [recordID]) 
    VALUES ( CAST(N'2012-07-19 13:09:26.170' AS DateTime),  334)
```

when I try to insert into another database in another sever, got this error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 9
> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How to fix that?

Comment: Presumably you are using a non-American language for your `LOGIN` and thus `2012-07-19 13:09:26.170` is interpreted as the 7th day of the 19th month. Use a unambiguous format (such as `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`).

Comment: Add 'SET DATEFORMAT ymd' before executing the generated script

Comment: thank you Martin. "SET DATEFORMAT ymd" this fix my problem. Is there a way I can do to change its format before I generate script.